# Grouping rows from Pandas Dataframe with column value within 20% of first value in group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, rows

Say I have a Pandas Dataframe below:

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1.2 |
| 3 | 1.6 |
| 4 | 1.5 |
| 5 | 1.4 |
| 6 | 1.1 |

I would like to group the Values within 20% margin of the first element of the group.

| ID | value | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1.2 | 0 |
| 6 | 1.1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1.6 | 1 |
| 4 | 1.5 | 2 |
| 5 | 1.4 | 2 |

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["group"] = np.nan
group = 0
while (m := df["group"].isna()).any():
    val = df.loc[m.idxmax(), "value"]
    df.loc[m & (np.abs(df["value"] - val) <= val * 0.2), "group"] = group
    group += 1

print(df.sort_values(by="group"))
```

Prints:

```
   ID  value  group
0   0    1.0    0.0
2   2    1.2    0.0
6   6    1.1    0.0
1   1    2.0    1.0
3   3    1.6    1.0
4   4    1.5    2.0
5   5    1.4    2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with the help of a function to get the groups:

```py
def getGroups(df, group):
    nullGroupMask = df['group'].isna()
    first = df.loc[nullGroupMask, 'value'].iat[0]
    df.loc[(df['value'] <= first+first*0.20) & (nullGroupMask), 'group'] = group
    return df

df['group'] = float('nan')
group = 0
while True:
    df = getGroups(df, group)
    group += 1
    if not df['group'].isna().any():
        break

df = df.astype({'group':int}).sort_values('group')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   ID  value  group
0   0    1.0      0
2   2    1.2      0
6   6    1.1      0
1   1    2.0      1
3   3    1.6      1
4   4    1.5      1
5   5    1.4      1
```